# Como puedo crear base de datos localStorage en apache cordova

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes,

Quería saber de que manera puedo crear una base de datos localstorage porque he tenido problemas a la hora de realizarlo con IndexedDb debido a que no puedo relacionar dos tablas entre sí.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando creas una db del lado del cliente en html no tienes un modelo relacional como lo harias cuando usas Sql Server, Oracle, MySql, etc, es un modelo reducido estilo NoSql, en donde no se relacionan las entidades.

[IndexedDB Conceptos Básicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup/Conceptos_Basicos_Detras_De_IndexedDB)

Alli menciona

- **IndexedDB es orientada a objetos.** IndexedDB no es una base de datos relacional, con tablas, filas y columnas.
- **IndexedDB no utiliza SQL (Structured Query Language)**. En cambio usa consultas sobre un índice que producen un cursor. Éste puede
  utilizarse para iterar sobre el conjunto de resultados. Aqui es donde
  marca el [sistema NoSql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

Basicamente deberias diseñar los datos basandote en conceptos de NoSql, en donde grabas estructura de objetos.

Si quieres mantener relacion entre estos podrias persistir un objeto complejo en donde la entidad y sus relaciones esten en el mismo objeto que persistes.

En resumen no hay base de datos relacional del lado del cliente en html.

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro.Es que he estado buscando un montón de información para poder relacionar entre almacenes de objetos y nada.Por ello creo que debería de cambiar de tipo de base de datos ya que necesito tener dos tablas relacionadas.Una sería para todos los pacientes de la base de datos y otra para las pruebas que se le realizan a cada paciente.Pero nose por que tipo de base decantarme ya que estoy utilizando Apache cordova para la realización de la app móvil. Un saludo crackk

Comment: la verdad dudo que encuentre como hacerlo porque en el cliente los datos no se relacionan. por eso te decia que investigues como debes diseñar la estructura de datos en base a NoSql, o sea los objetos que guardes ya deberian estar relacionados cuando defines la relacion entre objetos

Comment: Es que ya tengo creado los dos almacenes de objetos y se guardan bien los datos en ambos pero el problema radica en relacionarlos.Yo se que sería abriendo dos transacciones de ambos almacenes de objetos pero nose como relacionarlos con un objeto en particular.He buscado mucha info y no veo ninguna función que realice eso en IndexedDB.

Comment: No ves ninguna funcion porque no existe ninguna, vuelvo a remarcar que IndexedDB se basa en NoSql (no es una db relacional) y en este tipo de db no existen las relaciones. Si quieres relacionar objetos en este tipo de db debes crear uan estructura de datos que este relacionada y eso es lo que persistes

Comment: Muchas gracias me pondré a ello.Un saludo.